# Here API: Can map tiles be more detailed, like OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, here-api

There seem to be a huge difference in details when comparing OSM tiles to HERE tiles for Sweden:

To the left - OSM. To the right, HERE. Same location:

[image]

As you can see, the OSM tiles are way more detailed. I haven't found a way on here.com to change this. Am I missing something, or are the HERE tiles just less detailed?

The URL I'm using:

```
https://{0}.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/{1}/{2}/{3}/256/png8?
```

Comment: OpenStreetMap is crowdsourced, so there's no need to hire people to map every small path that there might exist. They/we do it for free. Probably HERE just doesn't have all the details.

Comment: You should point what's the URL you are using. The `style` and `t` params may be useful to you. https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/resource-map.html#resource-map__param-style

Comment: Hey @MarkusKauppinen I am aware, i just wanted to see if I missed something in the HERE API =)

Comment: @ssice Of course, stupid of me. Added =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of details as e.g. pedestrian paths or private streets are not supported within the Here Map tile service. But you an at least check here the different map styles in an easier way: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/mrs_options